# Is it possible to connect two devices without port forwarding?

Tags: networking, port, router

I learned to write a client and server application and how to connect them. The server host has to forward a port in the router to be able to a establish a connection.

Is it possible to connect two devices in the same network without port forwarding/triggering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The server host has to forward a port in the router to be able to establish a connection.

You have this back to front. The *router* has to forward a port to the *server host* in order for *clients outside the router* to be able to form connections.

Clients inside the router, i.e. in the same subnet as the server host, can connect directly.

Comment: Ah, I think I just got it. When I'm inside the same network I just connect to the lan-ip not the wan-ip,  right?

Comment: Correct. And the internal port number, if different.

Answer (score -1):

Yes as long as the devices are in the same network, no port forwarding is required.

Whenever a server is inside a NAT and you try to access it from outside, you have to configure port forwarding in your router.

Example:

You create a server running on port 8080 with IP 192.168.1.12

Suppose your router's public IP is 10.2.2.5

So you need to enable port forwarding in your router for port 8080 to 192.168.1.12:8080

Then you can access that server from outside with 10.2.2.5:8080